# Build.xml for Mac OS

Tags: macos, ant, build.xml

I have a build.xml to execute junit Java files. Will the following build.xml work fine on MAC OS or do I have to make any changes should in the XML (I mean with respect to OSX should we need to change anything)?

```
<project name="JunitTest" default="test" basedir=".">
   <property name="testdir" location="test" />
   <property name="srcdir" location="src" />
   <property name="full-compile" value="true" />
   <path id="classpath.base"/>
   <path id="classpath.test">
      <pathelement location="/lib/junit-4.10.jar">
      <pathelement location="${testdir}" />
      <pathelement location="${srcdir}" />
      <path refid="classpath.base" />
   </path>
   <target name="clean" >
      <delete verbose="${full-compile}">
         <fileset dir="${testdir}" includes="**/*.class" />
      </delete>
   </target>
   <target name="compile" depends="clean">
      <javac srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="${testdir}" >
         <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
      </javac>
   </target>
   <target name="test" depends="compile">
      <junit>
         <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
         <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
         <test name="TestMessageUtil" />
      </junit>
   </target>
</project>
```

Comment: There is no `/lib/junit-4.10.jar` in the base install. Add that library somewhere within your project.

Comment: Ant is cross-platform. Why would you need to change anything? What happens if you build your project using this ant file?

Comment: sure sure <pathelement location="D:/ACOE/JunitTest/lib/junit-4.10.jar">

Comment: (@ JB Nizet) one of my client needs to run my application in mac os using ANT , so need clarifications whether no changes has to be made to my build.xml will it work fine

Comment: will mac os will recognize each element similar to windows

Comment: If all your paths reference existing locations, if the JDK is correctly installed, etc., there's no reason to change anything. Only a test on the target machine will tell you if everything is fine.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks a lot for u r quick response, now m bit clear and will some how try to execute the same in target machine